# Ubuntu 21.04: wi-fi network disappears in middle of session

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, 21.04

I've been experiencing problems with the wifi going down all of a sudden.

I already tried some solutions I found here but to no avail.
It only solved part of the problem. Now If I restart I have wifi, whereas before it could go either way and sometimes the mouse did not work.

I've already updated the kernel to 5.13.4-051304-generic.
I've already installed the updated driver from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz

If I go to wi-fi through Activities it shows wi-fi network not found.

outputs:

while wi-fi not working

```
$lspci -nn
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
```

```
$sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b4200000-b4201fff
```

```
$sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
```

while wi-fi working:

```
$lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               380928  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              897024  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

```
$sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 78
       serial: d0:c6:37:e6:26:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.4-051304-generic firmware=36.ad812ee0.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.1.184 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:b4200000-b4201fff
```

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
requested outputs:

[grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WZHHwhRnJw/)

[sudo dmesg | grep -i iwlwifi](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rrbXVprK79/)

[sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CJYkpKJ8yz/)

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Did your problem begin BEFORE or AFTER you upgraded the kernel and the wireless firmware? The 5.13.4 kernel was probably not the right thing to do. Is this a laptop or desktop computer? Edit your question and show me `sudo dmesg | grep -i iwlwifi` and `grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*`. No screenshots please. Use copy/paste. After pasting, select the pasted text and click the {} button to properly format it. If the output is very large, use paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: You might try updating the firmware: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/all/linux-firmware/download Afterwards, does the problem remain? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema the problem began before. I upgraded the kernel and firmware trying to solve it. 

I've now updated the firmware like @chili555 recommended and the problem persists.

I've edited the question to include the logs.

I've also tried to repair packages with ```sudo apt dist-upgrade```:

Nothing worked so far.

Comment: I'd reseat the modem card in its slot. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, did you mean doing ```sudo modprobe``` ? I did that and apparently it worked. It hasn't caused any problem in the last 30 hours. It was affecting me at least twice a day... Fingers crossed. I'll report back.

Comment: @mehrlicht No, I meant to physically reseat the modem card in its slot. This is to eliminate a connection problem. A modprobe wouldn't have fixed it, as the driver gets reloaded during a boot/reboot.